# Concatenate lists with extend method

Tags: python

Suppose such a dict with multiple items:

```
d = {'foo':['c', 'a', 't'], 'bar':['d', 'o', 'g']}
```

I'd like to produce

```
    l = ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g']
    In [75]: l = []
        ...: for i in d.values():
        ...:     l.extend(i)
        ...: print(l)
    ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

Try to implement it within one line using `extend` method.

```
    In [76]: [ [].extend(i) for i in d.values() ]
    Out[76]: [None, None]
    In [79]: [ list().extend(i) for i in d.values()]
    Out[79]: [None, None]
```

What's the principles behind list comprehension to output `[None, None]` ?

It's facile to be achieved by

```
    In [78]: [i for j in d.values() for i in j]
    Out[78]: ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

Is it possible to be done with `extend` methond in single line?

Comment: `extend` method updates the existing list(the list which calls the extend ) and returns `None`.

Comment: `extend` modifies the list in-place and  the return value of `extend` is None

Comment: TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given) @Norrius

Comment: @Tool If you want a one-liner, this should do: `import itertools; list(itertools.chain(*d.values()))`. [Docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain) Note that the order of elements in `.values()` might be not well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

straight answer: The result you desire can not be constructed in one line with `extend`

As many already mentioned in comment `extend` modifies list and returns None.

You are not getting result because you wrote:
`[].extend(i)` in list comprehension

for each iteration your code will construct new list element `[]` and extend it with iteration value `i` you passed but it isn't stored anywhere so your code will perform operation but you won't get desire result because you didn't constructed a list before to avoid it you need to write code like this:

```
l=[]  # create a list first
[l.extend(i) for i in d.values()]  # for each iteration list l will be extended
print(l)  # ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

This comply with the principle of [Command–query separation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) devised by Bertrand Meyer.
It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.

[Design by contract - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)

[Fluent interface - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)